# Can't connect to internet via SOCKS5 proxy server

Tags: proxy, socks, dante

I have configured SOCKS5 proxy server in AWS with dante and it runs fine.

when I try the following command in CMD

```
curl -L -x socks5://user:password@23.29.xx.xx:1313 http://www.google.com/
```

it works,

But when I configure my LAN proxy configs, it can't access to the internet via any browser.

for CURL proxy server works but for browsers it doesn't.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is, I have enabled the user authentication in the server. Unlikely in HTTP proxy servers, there is no signin popup in socks5. This was fixed after I added the username and password.

Comment: Bro  i am having the same problem i even installed an extention to connect via proxy and provide authentication infos (FoxyProxy) but still having the same problem.